# How do I force monitors to stay on even when on the lock screen on 15.04

Tags: 15.04, suspend

I am having issues with Ubuntu 15.04 not allowing me to keep my monitors from going to sleep when it is locked. (There are issues that occur when they wake up, and want to avoid that.)

I have adjusted "Turn screen off when inactive for:" to "Never" under Brightness & Lock. As well as turned "Suspend when inactive for" to "Don't suspend" in Power. However after only a few minutes I find the monitors to have gone to sleep.

Again, just want the monitors to ALWAYS have signal running to them.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Edit: xset -q output

```
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  no    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0

DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Disabled
```

Comment: post output of `xset -q`

Comment: I imagine these are the two you are referencing - Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Disabled

Comment: yeah, i thought maybe whatever you did hadn't disabled dpms

Comment: do you have a screensaver?

Comment: No screensaver. However I have noticed that it dims pretty soon after it locks. But if I move the mouse before that time, it takes longer (possibly doesn't even dim, haven't tried it for extended period). So it seems there must be a  setting with the lock itself to automatically dim after locking?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing and using xscreensaver. It does everything the gnome-screensaver screenlock does, except that the unlock menu is ugly. It also keeps signal going to your monitors. It's not exactly what you want, but it might work. Also, I don't know how energystar works, but maybe if you blank the screen, even if the monitor says its on, energystar will still take the initiative to put the monitor to sleep. If you're running a screensaver, there's definitely a signal.